# How to align <iframe> vertically?

Tags: css, html

All that I want to be able to do is take the  tag and vertically align it with the page. I do not know if I have to put the  tag inside another tag in order to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

iframe {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe width="800" height="500"">

</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a fixed width or a liquid width that adjusts to window resize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/UFMP7/1/

The trick is to play with the margin and the top offset properties of the nested element.

In this case, given a parent div (A) of 300px, I've offset the nested div (B) by 50% of 300, which is 150. So B is positioned 150px down from the top of the A container. However, we aren't finished. In order to get the center of B to match the center of A, we are required to apply the negative 50% of B's height to the margin-top property. This centers it and the math checks out.

It's even easier if you know the dimensions of everything in pixels.

Feel free to change the A width or height. It'll center dynamically.

```
div#a
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;

    /* important stuff below */
    display: inline-block;  
}

div#b
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;

    /* important stuff below */
    position: relative;
    margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
    top: 50%;  
}
```

As such, I'd suggest wrapping your iframe in a div. It gives you a bit more control. Then again, I'm one of those excessive div wrappers...

Answer (score 3):

Use flex. It is more straight forward.

```css
/* Here just for context */
html,
body,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* This is whats needed */
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe width="300" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V17ij5Ap1pA"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to center the iframe , giving a width to its selector should do the trick:

```
iframe {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor way to do it, but it's the most compatible with all browsers. Other methods have their problems.

1. Create table that has height = 100% and one row with one cell in it.
2. Set the cell's style to `vertical-align: middle; width: 800px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;`.
3. in stylesheet add

   html, body{
      height: 100%;
   }

Once again, this is a bit of a bad way to do it, because you are using tables to organise visual layout, but it has benifits

- simple
- doesn't require HTML 5 on browser
- compatible with pretty much every browser back to IE 5
- doesn't need javascript

ammendment: make sure you specify min-width and min-height in body style to keep iFrame always visible.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
<table height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center">
      <iframe width="800" height="500"></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in **CSS**

```
body{ height:100% }
```

Comment: It worked for me thanks. Non of the style stuff on-line for either HTML or CSS helped me get a google map aligned to the center of the page. I started to think that it was a domain problem but the table fixed it.